# Where do I put the code for the new Search API in Xcode 7 / iOS 9?

Tags: swift2, xcode7, ios9

Okay, so I understood the video pretty well about the Search API but where on earth do I put my code? I am really confused on that, like where would I put it to make it functional? Also, how do you code the part where when you tap on it from search, it opens to that certain view controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can put your searchable code anywhere in your codebase depending on what object you are actually trying to search. 
Once you add the object as a CSSearchableItem, it will then be available in spotlight. 
The searchable item will have a unique identifier given by you, when you create it.

You also need to implement a new method in your app delegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray *restorableObjects))restorationHandler {
```

So when the searchable item is clicked from the spotlight, the above method in your app delegate will be called.

The below link gives more information:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-SW3

Comment: Can I get a Swift example :(.